# ¿Cómo añado elementos en un array en Java?

Tags: java, matrices, matriz, bluej

Estoy tratando de hacer un tres en raya y para ello he creado una matriz, que es el tablero. Mi plan es que cuando le toque a un jugador, este especifique la fila y la columna y en esta de disponga un 1 para el Jugador 1 y un 0 para el Jugador 2. Bien, pues el problema que tengo es que una vez obtenida la fila y la columna me sale el error "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[][]" en el return.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Jugador1 {
    private static Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int[][] dato(int tab[][]){
       
        System.out.println("-Jugador 1.");
        System.out.println("--Fila: ");
        int f = t.nextInt();
        System.out.println("--Columna: ");
        int c = t.nextInt();
        return tab[f][c] = 1;
    }
}
```

Se que el código está incompleto y que por ejemplo me falta discernir si la fila y la columna están entre 1 y 3, pero solo era una prueba para asignar un valor a una matriz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te está pasando es que al escribir:

```
return tab[f][c] = 1;
```

está retornando un entero, el 1 que acabas de asignar a la posición `tab[f][c]`, y no el array tab que es lo que espera la función según la definiste.

Tendrás que hacer la asignación en una línea, y el return del array en otra:

```
tab[f][c] = 1;
return tab;
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona.